# Calling event dispatch thread

Tags: java, swing

I have a main class which extends JFrame.

I add panels to this instance of frame which consist of JTable and other Swing components.

In this main class in the "**public static void main**", I set swing event dispatch thread.

I add panels to this instance frame, and initiate:

```
this.setTitle("Test");
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.pack();
this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
this.setVisible(true);
```

etc...

All fine up to here.

Now, for JTable it has a listener and when a row is clicked it opens up a new instance of a class InfoDialog.

In this InfoDialog I add Swing components as usual.

I have another dispatch thread in JDialog like this:

```
class InfoDialog  {
    JDialog jd;
    public void initGUI() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                 jd = new JDialog();
            jd.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            jd.setTitle("Buy");
            jd.setDefaultCloseOperation(jd.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            jd.pack();
            jd.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jd.setVisible(true);
    }});
   } 
}
```

Putting the event dispatch thread solves the errors I'm getting (probably because its blocking the current thread previosuly), and my question is, is this the right way to do it?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Q: What errors led you to choose doing your own .invokeLater()?  Q: What do *you* think might be a problem with your approach?  For the record: No, I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing.  IMHO...

Comment: What happened was, when I click on row and set new instance of InfoDialog there are also properties and other instances I set right after this that work with the InfoDialog instance, which are only become set after I close the InfoDialog instance. With another event dispatch thread in the InfoDialog instance itself it sets those properties at the same time, otherwise it throws errors when I try to perform actions on the UI of InfoDialog which reference other instances that would not have been set otherwise. hope this makes sense.

Comment: Also, it seems that with ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL set on the dialog this occurs and I have to use dispatch thread.

Comment: If modality type is set to null, it basically works without the event dispatch thread but I don't want this type of behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you should only be creating and interacting with the dialog (and all other UI components) from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

You can (at some extent), ensure this by calling `EventQueue.invokeLater` from your `main` method to start with.  This ensures that most of the UI is already been called from within the context of the EDT.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //...Your UI code here...
        }
    });
}
```

It should be safe to assume that you are within the EDT at all other times.  It should be the responsibility of the caller to ensure this, not your components.  I often create "safe" factory methods to make it easier to construct some UI components (things like progress indicators for example) which are designed and documented to be thread safe.

Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.

Comment: I agree, I believe this is exactly how I'm implementing it now. Calling the EventQueue.invokeLater on the main class for main GUI, then EventQueue.invokeLater on the JDialog GUI instances.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `EventQueue.invokeLater` within the constructor of the dialog.  If you are doing this, then the dialog is been constructed out side the EDT which is bad.  Before  constructing the dialog, make sure you are within the context of the EDT, you can use `EventQueue.isDispatchingThread()` to check...

Comment: But I know each instance is not part of the main EDT, how can I ensure it is in that case? Pass a reference?

Comment: There is only one EDT.  If `EventQueue.isDispatchingThread()` returns false then you're code is executing in a thread other then the EDT.  You component code shouldn't (unless you need to design it otherwise) be concerned with this, it should be the responsibility of the caller to ensure this.  So BEFORE you create the dialog, if you think that you might be out side the EDT, check `EventQueue.isDispatchingThread()`. If it is `false` then you should use `EventQueue.invokeLater` to re-sync with the EDT...

Comment: Hey, I wrote a question that mentions you, swing and thread safety over on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/295230/why-is-it-the-callers-responsibility-to-ensure-thread-safety-in-gui-programming). I hope you can take a look

Answer (score 0):

There is only one AWT EDT. (Well there can be multiple in Applets and WebStart, but effectively just one.)

What's happening with your `invokeLater` is that an event is placed on the `EventQueue`, then execution goes back through the caller of `initGUI`, previously queued events are dispatched and then then your `run` method is executed.

Possibly you shoul move the call to `initGUI()` further down your code.

Comment: thanks. I have definitely learned my lesson after tens of hours working on debugging this.